# Query a database usng an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

When I do this I am only getting one result back `Fantasy0.1429` when I should be getting 7 different ones any one know what I am doing wrong.

```
$userid = $_SESSION['sess_id'];

$genreQuery = $con ->query ("select distinct(genre) from movies");

$movieGenre = array();

while($row = $genreQuery->fetch_object())  {
$movieGenre[] = $row;
}

foreach($movieGenre as $MGenre){
 $query = $con ->query 
 (" select '$MGenre->genre' genre, IFNULL(count(*)/(select count(*) from user_movie_ratings where user_id = '$userid'),0) rating
    from   user_movie_ratings umr,
    movies m
    where  umr.user_id = '$userid'
    and    umr.movie_id = m.id
    and    m.genre = '$MGenre->genre'; ");

$movieTitle = array();

while($row = $query->fetch_object())  {
$movieTitle[] = $row;
}
}
```

Then I echo it out later

```
<?php foreach($movieTitle as $movie): echo $movie->genre; echo $movie->rating; endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: What's the error and what's displaying ?

Comment: there is no error the problem is that I should be getting 7 results back where as I am only getting one

Comment: What `var_dump($movieTitle)` is showing ?

Comment: try to print the request and run it in a phpmyadmin

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#11 (2) { ["genre"]=> string(7) "Fantasy" ["rating"]=> string(6) "0.1429" } }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move away the instanciation of your array before the foreach like:

```
// Some code ...
$movieTitle = array();

foreach($movieGenre as $MGenre){
 $query = $con ->query 
 (" select '$MGenre->genre' genre, IFNULL(count(*)/(select count(*) from user_movie_ratings where user_id = '$userid'),0) rating
    from   user_movie_ratings umr,
    movies m
    where  umr.user_id = '$userid'
    and    umr.movie_id = m.id
    and    m.genre = '$MGenre->genre'; ");

while($row = $query->fetch_object())  {
$movieTitle[] = $row;
}
}
```